# Simple variable passed into EJS template is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am learning NodeJS and have built a very simple app that renders an EJS template passing a string variable. When I try to run it however, it says the variable "greeting" is undefined:

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        greeting: "Hello World"
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

index.ejs:

```
<h1>Testing out EJS</h1>

<h2>Greeting is: <%= greeting %></h2>
```

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out that the solution here was much simpler than I thought. If you're running your server while making changes to project files the changes will not necessarily get picked up. In order to avoid this, every change needs to be followed by a server restart.

With that being said, a tool called Nodemon (https://github.com/remy/nodemon) is helpful for development, as it restarts the server for you automatically following a change.